# Как перезаписать дата атрибут js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как перезаписать `data-default=""`, он сохраняет его где-то или как его перезаписать?

```js
$('.close').click(function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('closeFilter')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');

    $(this).parent().find('.display').html(obj.dd.attr("data-default"));

    $(this).removeClass('closeFilter');
    Controller.filterIsotope();

    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="columns large-3">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="wrapper-dropdown" data-default="Один">
        <span class="close"><i class="icon icon-plus-close"></i></span>
        <div class="display">Один</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns large-3">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="wrapper-dropdown" data-default="Два">
        <span class="close"><i class="icon icon-plus-close"></i></span>
        <div class="display">Два</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns large-3">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="wrapper-dropdown" data-default="Три">
        <span class="close closeFilter"><i class="icon icon-plus-close"></i></span>
        <div class="display">Три</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns large-3">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="wrapper-dropdown" data-default="Четыре">
        <span class="close closeFilter"><i class="icon icon-plus-close"></i></span>
        <div class="display">Четыре</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: а чем классический `setAttribute('data-default','Три')` не угодил?

Answer (score 0):

Если надо удалить data-атрибут, то можно воспользоваться [соответствующим методом](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/)

```
someObj.removeData('default');
```

Если записать в него другое значение, то

```
someObj.data('default', '')
```